# How do I hide a UIButton, wired to a Segue, in a UITableView row?

Tags: ios, uibutton, tableview

I have a `UIButton` in a `UITableView` row which launches a segue. I want to hide the button until the user selects Yes or No from a segmented control in the `UITableView`. I plan to un-hide the button in the `IBAction` wired to the segmented control.  Right now, I'm saving the pointer to the specific table cell, where the button resides, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to a member variable (on second thought, I should probably make that a weak `@property` so it doesn't leak memory when the tableview leaves?). Anyway, how would I obtain a reference to the actual button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so I can just hide the button, and not the entire row?

I tried hooking up an `IBOutlet` to the `UIButton` but got a "couldn't compile connection" error in Xcode which I assumed was due to the button also being referenced for the segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the button a tag i.e. 1000 in Interface Builder then in the code you can access the button via the tableviewcell i.e.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[cell viewForTag:1000];
```

That will allow access to the button assuming cell is a valid tableviewcell

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm looking for, but how do I get the "cell" from within IBAction fired from the segmented control? Is it within the `id` somewhere?

Comment: you would have to either have a reference or do the cellForRowAtindexPath as you were doing previously. If you have a code example of what your doing it would help to assist you

Comment: Thanks. The code is just an IBAction with nothing really in it not even worth posting. I'll hang onto the member variable and see how it flys.